# Make addon for Firefox 23 or higher

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing a simply addon that modify DOM for current page with Javascript.
I am compiling with last SDK version but I want use addon in Firefox 23 usually.

How can get this?? Something parameter in compile time for fix this?

Sorry my bad English, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

This is completely unsupported, please don't use older versions of Firefox, they almost certainly contain bad bugs that have been fixed.

Comment: Sorry canuckistani. I can't update firefox version because the computer is of my work. I don't have administrator permissions for install and update software, only addons in firefox.

Comment: I'm really sorry to hear that. The SDK release most closely related in time to Firefox 23 was actually SDK 1.15. More info here: https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2013/12/12/announcing-add-on-sdk-1-15/

Comment: Perfect, the SDK 1.16 is compatible with 21.0 or higher. The file structure and compile mode is the same of the last SDK (1.17).